# Connecting Python to arduino - check if string is equal to do task

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial, arduino-uno

I am passing a string from a computer with python(using `pyserial`) to my arduino uno and if it is equal to a set value, I need it to perform a task - I haven't even made it far enough to get the set values, I can't even get something to happen if it is passed at all. I just copied some of the blink code, to run if anything is received on serial and sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't, seemingly without reason. If anyone has an example of how to do this or knows where I am going wrong help would be appreciated.

Python Code

```py
import serial
import time

def write():
    arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=.1)
    time.sleep(1) #give the connection a second to settle
    arduino.write(str.encode("Hello from Python!"))

write()
```

Arduino Uno Code

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
    char data = Serial.read();
    char str[2];
    str[0] = data;
    str[1] = '\0';
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    delay(1000);     
  }
}
```

Comment: When using two systems that can be buggy a good approach would be to debug them separatedly. The python code is very basic and I wouldn't see it as the culprit. So let's debug the arduino part. Can you use the arduino serial terminal and check if you observe the same buggy behaviour by sending strings manually?

Comment: @Fra93 when I do `Serial.write("hello world');` just before the if statement, it does blink but this is not replicated when sending it from the python script

Comment: Try using a serial monitor (Arduino IDE's or Platform IO) and see if you can send data using that.

Comment: @sleepystar96 nothing happens when I directly type into the Serial montior

Comment: I just realized, your loop() doesn't interrupt, so your board might not be switching to check the other running threads. Add a `delay(100)` before your if statement, should fix it!

Comment: @sleepystar96 you mean just before the first `digitalwrite`?

Comment: no, before `if(Serial.available() > 0) {`

Comment: @sleepystar96 that seems to have fixed it, how would I go about checking the equality of a string to a predetermined value and then executing something?

Comment: Likely using `strcmp(data, "myString")` https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp

Comment: Might also want to use `Serial.readstring()` instead https://www.arduino.cc/reference/tr/language/functions/communication/serial/readstring/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a delay(100) before your `if(Serial.available() > 0) {` statement.

More about this:

Your Arduino only has 1 core. If you do not have a delay() in your loop(), then the loop will take up 100% cpu usage all the time. This stops it from being able to execute background concurrent threads, e.g. to listen to Serial port, do bluetooth/wifi stuff, etc..

The delay() allows the main loop (or any thread) to sleep, so that the arduino's interrupt can execute other concurrent threads.